# Number of cut points and non-cut points in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have determined that there are two non-cut points in $[0,1]$, one non-cut point in $[0,1)$ so I am guessing there are no non-cut points in $\mathbb{R}$? Or maybe I am completely off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to guess. For *every* $x\in \Bbb R$, $\Bbb R-x=(-\infty,x)\cup (x,\infty)$ is disconnected, so $\Bbb R$ admits no non-cut points. If $n\geqslant 2$ and $x\in\Bbb R^n$, then $\Bbb R^n-x$ is connected, since it is in fact path-connected. Thus for $n\geqslant 2$ *every* point of $\Bbb R^n$ is a non-cut point.